# Azure Training Kit

Tags: azure

I downloaded the Azure training kit but when I open my up one of the labs, some projects do not load.

For eg the PhotoAlbum solution the PhtoAlbumService is missing and mentions the error

"The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Windows Azure Tools\1.6\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\WATK\Labs\ExploringWindowsAzureStorageVS2010\Source\Ex04-WorkingWithDrives\end\CS\PhotoAlbumService\PhotoAlbumService.ccproj"

If there are missing files how do I find them to get them installed.
It also mentions that the
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient is missing.

Answer (score 0):

From memory I think the training kit has a dependency checker (Web Installer checks your environment) which will make sure you have the latest and greatest of everything before you get going. I suggest you run this on your Dev machine to see what is missing.

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/other-resources/training-kit/

HTH

Comment: I tried that an I get an error message saying "Invalid namespace"?